# Why Won't My Images Display? Feel like I've tried everything

Tags: html, image

No matter what I try, images won't display in my browser.  I've made sure file names were matching, that the directories were correct, etc. I've tried different images just to see if anything will load.

Here is an example of my code. The image and index file are in the same folder. Can anyone help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src=“rollingrick.jpg” alt=“Rick”>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did u tried like this "../rollingrick.jpg" or "../../rollingrick.jpg" or src="file:///C:/webpages/images/rollingrick.jpg" ?

Comment: I did try those. It is in the same directory as the html file.  I even copied the full path of the image and still no luck.

Comment: Maybe the browser doesn't like the smart quotes

Comment: I'm sorry, could you expand on that?  I am still learning.  Thank you.

Comment: The smart quotes around `rollingrick.jpg`. Try it with normal quotes.

Comment: I tried typing this out in Brackets instead of TextEdit and that worked.  Thank you! I guess it must have been a setting in TextEdit.

Comment: did you tried {{url('/images/rollingrick.jpg')}} ?